# How to use psake from a batch file?

Tags: build, batch-file, psake

What I want is a one file I can double-click that will run the required build process using psake.

I'm new to psake and PowerShell so be gentle :-).

What I have now are 3 files:

File 1: Build.bat

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File .\Build.ps1 %1
```

File 2: Build.ps1

```
Import-Module .\psake.psm1
Invoke-psake .\BuildTasks.ps1 $args
```

File 3: BuildTasks.ps1

```
task default -depends Verify, Joe

task Verify {
    write-host "hello from Verify!"
}

task Joe {
    write-host "hello from Joe"
}
```

Is there anyway to merge Build.ps1 and BuildTasks.ps1 into one file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this with

```
powershell -Command "& {Import-Module .\psake.psm1; Invoke-psake .\BuildTasks.ps1 %*}"
```

which gets rid of the `build.ps1` file.

Comment: Johannes. Thanks heaps. Just one all fix. %1 is required instead of $args.

PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Import-Module .\psake.psm1; Invoke-psake .\BuildTasks.ps1 %1}"

Answer (score 1):

Psake comes with a powershell script "psake.ps1" which wraps the call for you.  It looks like:

```
import-module .\psake.psm1
invoke-psake @args
remove-module psake
```

So your batch script looks like

```
powershell {path-to-module}\psake.ps1 .\buildTasks.ps1
```

Comment: the psake.ps1 file you mentioned works fine for passing tasks into the invoke-psake call but the moment you attempt to pass hashtables (the -parameters and -properties arguments) it fails. At least I haven't been able to get it to work.